# Как правильно выполнить и экспортировать SVG sprite из UI kit в Figma?

Tags: ios, svg, ui

Интересуют правила проектирования спрайта для элементов интерфейса
дашборда аналитики на основе дизайна и UI kit, подготовленных в Figma.

Насколько я понимаю, если выгружать по единичному изображению - это дает
3 серии SVG-элементов: по состояниям до события (наведения/клика) - default, при наведении на элемент (hover), при клике (target). Но по сумме они будут весить больше, чем один совокупный спрайт.

Цель задачи: сделать правильный оптимизированный спрайт с SVG-графикой для интерфейса дашборда.

Answer (score 0):

Это достаточно просто.
Условное деление на 3 строки:

- default элемент№1 элемент№2 ... элемент№N
- hover элемент№1 элемент№2 ... элемент№N
- target элемент№1 элемент№2 ... элемент№N

Каждый элемент представляет собой box (квадрат по форме), куда вписано векторное изображение (надеюсь ясно что SVG лучше PNG для масштабирования).

Отступы между квадратами элементов в размер квадрата или в половину его стороны. Там даже где-то формула есть, [читал в самоучителе - про SVG спрайты](https://www.litres.ru/book/e-u-polyakov/vektornaya-grafika-dlya-nachinauschih-teoriya-i-praktika-tehn-68397985/) (посмотрите в книге поиском найдете).